# jQuery - ignore double AJAX calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, double-click

I have AJAX calls attached in multiple places (unfortunately not only buttons, but also links, forms and other stuff), I know how to handle this manually (find every place I do an AJAX call and then block / overlay the button during first call), I'm wondering if there's a way to do it more automagically?

If we're talking jQuery - maybe a plugin? Something that will just work? :)

It'd be perfect to have something like:

```
if clicked element has .ajax class 
  block all ajax requests if the current one is still live
```

I'd then add .ajax class to every button/link/whatever triggering the request and voila. Does anything like this exist?

Comment: if you would post your code maybe someone would help you, at the moment you can have a look here: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/04/03/strategies-for-dealing-with-multiple-ajax-calls.

Comment: `$.hasClass()` exists, but I may be misunderstanding what you're talking about doing

Comment: @vove there's not more code, I have countless AJAX requests in every part of the app, I think I want to block double AJAX requests globally. I'm talking about usual .click() $.ajax requests mostly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can to create a global variable:

```
loadingAjax = false;
```

whenever an event triggers, you turn this variable to TRUE by using:

```
$("selector").click(function(){
  if(!loadingAjax){
    loadingAjax = true;
    $.ajax(options)..
  }
});
```

And you should turn loadingAjax back into false when the ajax stops:

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    loadingAjax = false
});
```